# How to merge two cells in gridview

Tags: gridview, merge

I have some data in a gridview,  in this format:

```
A     B
1     
2     adeel
3
4     sml
```

Now I want to merge the row with the empty cell under the B column.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to merge the rows in a same column, you choule use the code like this :

```
public static void GroupRows(GridView GridView1, int cellNum)
{
    int i = 0, rowSpanNum = 1;
    while (i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.Rows[i];
        for (++i; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrNext = GridView1.Rows[i];
            if (gvr.Cells[cellNum].Text != "" && gvrNext.Cells[cellNum].Text == "") ///here, chould change the term to suit other conditions, such like merging the same content of different rows in a same column.
            {
                gvrNext.Cells[cellNum].Visible = false;
                rowSpanNum++;
            }
            else
            {
                gvr.Cells[cellNum].RowSpan = rowSpanNum;
                rowSpanNum = 1;
                break;
            } 
            if (i == GridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                gvr.Cells[cellNum].RowSpan = rowSpanNum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "layout:coloumnSpan" or "layout:rowSpan"   to make an object "merge" over two columns or rows as required. Simply set the value to 2 for it to merge over 2 rows/columns.

Comment: How do you do this programmatically?