# Android: How to display an AdView in a row after every n-th row in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, admob

I have a GridView with two columns and I want to show a native ad after every n-th row. I have searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find any solution.

I have tried a few libraries/sdks like https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter but have been unable to solve my problem.

Code Try:

```
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyHolder holder = null;
        boolean showAd = proVersion == false && (position % 8 == k);
        if (showAd) {
            AdView adView = adList.get(position);
            if (adView == null) {
                AdView adViewNew = new AdView((Activity) context, AdSize.BANNER, context.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.adId));
                adViewNew.loadAd(Utils.getAdRequest("gps", lat, lng, keywords));
                adList.add(position, adViewNew);
                return adViewNew;
            } else {
                return adView;
            }
        } else if (row == null || row instanceof AdView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MyHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.textName.setText(items.get(position).getName());

        // more code

        return row;
    }
```

[I want to achieve something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkd8f.jpg)

Comment: that have you tried? I mean not only lib urls but code

Comment: @Vyacheslav I have provided a code try as well

Comment: is ` if (showAd) {` fired or not?

Comment: It does get fired and I get an ad in a single grid cell and not in whole row.

Comment: Read my answer. I've added a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AdmobAdapter sample example working fine.
Method initRecyclerViewItems() Inside MainActivity_RecyclerView_Express file need to be updated.

```
/*Code to be replaced*/
rvMessages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

/*Replace the above code with the below one*/
final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
rvMessages.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch (rvMessages.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 1:
                return 2;

            default:
                return 1;
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but.

In brief.

1. Create your custom adapter that extends your BaseAdapter.
2. Create your own class that stores your GridViewCell data.

e.g.

```
class MyStoredData {
public String myTextOfUsualElement = "";
public boolean isThisBannerElement = false;//or true if this row is banner
//the other setup
}
```

3. inside `getView()` check if this element is banner:

> @Override
>           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>
> ```
> if (myStoredDataArrayList.get(position).isThisBannerElement) {
> //inflate here your banner
> } else {
> //inflate here your usual info
> }
>  //...
>     }
> ```

In order to merge rows, please, read this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12554312/1979882 or use TableLayout instead.

Comment: Could you please explain how to fit the ad to whole grid row instead of single grid cell? Thanks